# AWS DataSync could not detect any files in the source NFS filesystem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nfs, aws-datasync

I am trying to Sync the data from a On Premise VM to AWS S3 bucket using AWS Data Sync, I have already configured the AWS Data Sync Agent on the On Prem VM , The Agent is now  Online and we have also created a new task, The task is available in state.

As I am trying to sync the data from the NFS File System to S3 bucket using the task we get the below mentioned error:

**"DataSync could not detect any files in the source NFS filesystem"**

Comment: Hmm since you already got the Agent working at the source Location, have you checked the location's mount path and NFS version? If the location's configured NFS version is set to something explicit like 4.0/4.1, try setting it to Automatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was the NFS version.
Since it was a windows VM we tried disabling the older NFS versions and tried it did work when we selected the right version.

But we moved to SMB since it was easier to setup on Windows VM

AWS Data Sync agent uses below command to mount the share folder

```
mount -o uid=65534, gid=65534, file_mode=0755, dir_mode=0755, forceuid, forcegid, noperm, noacl,rsize=1048576, wsize=1048576, soft -o user=awsDS, password=, vers=2.1 -t cifs <MOUNT_TARGET> <MOUNT_PATH>
```